# Error al generar PDF con la libreria FPDF

Tags: php, ajax, fpdf

Estoy realizando un sitio web en el cual debe de generar reportes y haciendo algunas pruebas me arroja el siguiente error:

> %PDF-1.3
>   3 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>   4 0 obj
>   <>
>   stream
>   x�3R��2�35W(�r
>   Q�w3T04�30PISp
>       �Z*�[����(h,���I�Q�-�K�W�T�)*7�
>   endstream
>   endobj
>   1 0 obj
>   <
>   endobj
>   5 0 obj
>   <>
>   stream
>   x�]R�n�0��>��L�%�DI�8���~�%E*r�ﻻvҪHX�gvVk?/���Ῑ��`]�[�x5
>   �3\z��P�}����PO���j�Jݍ^���x6/f�����������|���4}�z�����}���@�,ۖ-��˺E�u�^�,���<�
>   �Z_�K� IQ����Yd����C�K��%q�8>�!J"V!2&bGģ%r"H��D��}2EL1n��h�j���e��"a*H����:��d��9c���[�X1~��"�3�g��Ñ�;O���)-�<%a�I9��8v�s�4z0�97Wcp���x�4�^���M�D*�
>   ��
>   endstream
>   endobj
>   6 0 obj
>   <
>   endobj
>   2 0 obj
>   <<
>   /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
>   /Font <<
>   /F1 6 0 R
>   >
>   /XObject <<
>   >
>   >
>   endobj
>   7 0 obj
>   <<
>   /Producer (FPDF 1.81)
>   /CreationDate (D:20180222042638)
>   >
>   endobj
>   8 0 obj
>   <<
>   /Type /Catalog
>   /Pages 1 0 R
>   >
>   endobj
>   xref
>   0 9
>   0000000000 65535 f 
>   0000000229 00000 n 
>   0000000868 00000 n 
>   0000000009 00000 n 
>   0000000087 00000 n 
>   0000000316 00000 n 
>   0000000750 00000 n 
>   0000000972 00000 n 
>   0000001048 00000 n 
>   trailer
>   <<
>   /Size 9
>   /Root 8 0 R
>   /Info 7 0 R
>   >
>   startxref
>   1097
>   %%EOF

El codigo `PHP` que tengo es el siguiente:

```
 <?php
        require 'fpdf.php';
        define('FPDF_FONTPATH','../../../lib/font');

        //$datos = json_decode($_POST['Datos']);

        class PDF extends FPDF
        {
        // Cabecera de página
        function Header()
        {
            // Logo
            $this->Image('../../../images/icons/logo1.jpg',10,8,33);
            // Arial bold 15
            $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
            // Movernos a la derecha
            $this->Cell(80);
            // Título
            $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
            // Salto de línea
            $this->Ln(20);
        }

        // Pie de página
        function Footer()
        {
            // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
            $this->SetY(-15);
            // Arial italic 8
            $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
            // Número de página
            $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
        }
        }

        // Creación del objeto de la clase heredada
        $pdf = new PDF();
        $pdf->AliasNbPages();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
        for($i=1;$i<=40;$i++)
        $pdf->Cell(0,10,'Imprimiendo línea número '.$i,0,1);
        $pdf->Output('D','archivo.pdf',false);
        ?>
```

Estoy accediendo al archivo php mediante ajax, el cual al dar clic en un boton se ejecuta el ajax:

```
function generarReporte() {
var datos = JSON.stringify(datosReportesTickets);
$.ajax({
    url: '../../users/admin/gen_pdf_adm/genpdfrep.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType : 'application/pdf',
    data: {Datos:datos},
})
        .done(function (data) {             
           alert(data);               

        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log("error");
        });

}
```

¿Quisiera saber a que se debe ese error y como puedo resolverlo?

El código que tengo es tal cual, realmente no se como resolver esto.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, pudiste solucionarlo, yo aún no encuentro como resolverlo

Comment: El problema viene por solicitar la descarga de un archivo a través de XHR, que no provoca la descarga del archivo en el navegador. Puedes ver soluciones propuestas aquí: [Problemas abriendo un archivo desde PHP en una nueva ventana](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/190667/problemas-abriendo-un-archivo-desde-php-en-una-nueva-ventana) y aquí: [Problema de compatibilidad en navegadores de jquey para descargar pdf](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/228902/problema-de-compatibilidad-en-navegadores-de-jquey-para-descargar-pdf/229000#229000).

Answer (score 1):

Agrega lo siguiente

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

antes de

```
$pdf->Output('D','archivo.pdf',false);
```

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera pude solucionar, el mismo problema que tu tenias, aunque yo utilizo otro Cliente (AngularJS) pero al usar JavaScript la solución debería de ser la misma:

Usar un evento **`onclick`** y cargar las variables que serán interpretadas por JavaScript.

**AngularJS**

```
//Funcion para generar certificado
  $scope.generarCertificado = function(nombre_contacto,
                                       apellido_contacto,
                                       nombre_curso,
                                       horas_curso,
                                       ciudad_curso,
                                       cargo_certificado)
  {
    var nombrePersona = nombre_contacto + ' ' + apellido_contacto;
    var curso  = nombre_curso;
    var horas  = horas_curso;
    var ciudad = ciudad_curso;
    var cargo  = cargo_certificado;

    window.open('Reportes/PDF/certificado.php?nombre='+ nombrePersona +'&curso='+ curso + '&horas='+ horas + '&ciudad='+ ciudad + '&cargo=' + cargo);    
  }
```

**FPDF - PHP**

```
<?php
include 'plantilla.php';

//Variables obtenidas

$nombre      = $_GET['nombre'];
$curso       = $_GET['curso'];
$horas       = $_GET['horas'];
$ciudad      = $_GET['ciudad'];
$cargo       = $_GET['cargo'];

//Variables de Fecha
setlocale(LC_TIME, "spanish");
$dia = date("d");
$mes = strftime("%B");
$ano = date("Y");


$pdf = new PDF('L', 'mm','A4');
$pdf->AddPage();

//Texto de citacion del certificado
$pdf->SetXY(120,20);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',16);
$pdf->Text(135,70,'Certifica que: ','C');
$pdf->Ln(15);

//Nombre de la persona a quien se le certifica
$pdf->SetXY(120,25);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',28);
$pdf->Text(60,90,utf8_decode(''. $nombre . ''),'C');
$pdf->Ln(15);

//Nombre del curso de la certificación
$pdf->SetXY(60,45);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','I',16);
$mid_x = 135; // the middle of the "PDF screen", fixed by now.
$text = utf8_decode('Participó en el curso "'). $curso . ' DEPORTIVA Y SEGURIDAD"';

//Intensidad horaria
$pdf->SetXY(120,25);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','I',16);
$pdf->Text(105,117,utf8_decode('Con una intensidad horaria de '). $horas . ' horas','C');
$pdf->Ln(15);

//Fecha de la expedición del certificado
$pdf->SetXY(120,25);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','BI',16);
$pdf->Text(60,127,utf8_decode('Este certificado se expide en la ciudad de ') . $ciudad . utf8_decode(', el día ') . $dia . ' de ' . $mes . ' de ' . $ano,'C' );
$pdf->Ln(15);

//Codigo de referencia del certificado
$pdf->SetXY(70,10);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,128);
$pdf->Text(257,17,'111-1853','C');



$pdf->output('D', CERTIFICADO-' . strtoupper($nombre) . '.pdf');

?>
```

**plantilla.php**

```
    <?php
  require('pdf/fpdf.php');

  /**
   *
   */
  class PDF extends FPDF
  {
    function Header()
    {
      $this->Image('Imagenes/certificado.png', 4,3,300,210);
      //$this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
      //$this->Cell(30  );
      //$this->Cell(120,10, 'Certificado de Asistencia', 0, 0, 'C');
    }
  }


 ?>
```

Por algún motivo no se pueden pasar variables convertidas a JSON, según el FAQ de FPDF :

> 8. Uso jQuery para generar el archivo PDF pero éste no se muestra. 
>      R/ No uses a AJAX request para obtener el PDF.

URL: http://www.fpdf.org/
FAQ - 8

Answer (score 1):

El problema que sufres es debido a la manera en la que solicitas el archivo PDF:

```
function generarReporte() {
    var datos = JSON.stringify(datosReportesTickets);
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../users/admin/gen_pdf_adm/genpdfrep.php',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/pdf',
        data: {Datos:datos},
    })
    .done(function (data) {             
        alert(data);               
    })
    .fail(function () {
        console.log("error");
    });
}
```

A través de XHR no puedes forzar la descarga de un archivo en el navegador, si no que esperas recibir datos que son almacenados en la variable `data` (el parámetro de `done()`).

Además, estás mostrando el contenido del PDF en el `alert()`, en vez de forzar al navegador que se descargue dicho archivo mediante el envío de un formulario o mediante una función como ésta:

```
function descargar(blob, nombre) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    /* Vamos a cargar los datos (siendo o no blob) en una matriz 
      y forzamos la creación de un nuevo blob */
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob([ blob ], { type: 'application/octet-stream' })
    );
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'perfil_' + nombre + '.pdf';
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

En cuyo caso deberías cambiar el `done()`:

```
    .done(function (data) {             
        descargar(data, 'archivo.pdf');               
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

El error viene de que $.ajax espera recibir texto y esta recibiendo un pdf.

Necesitas especificar el tipo content-type que espera recibir:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../../users/admin/gen_pdf_adm/genpdfrep.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType : 'application/pdf',
    data: {Datos:data}
})
```

Adicional cambiar en el codigo PHP `$pdf->Output();` por  `$pdf->Output('D',"nombre-del-archivo");` para que fuerce la descarga.

Fuente: http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/output.htm

Comment: no importa que el `.done` este vacio, lo que quisiera es que lo mostrara en otra pestaña

Comment: Cuando abres un pdf descargado se abre en el navegador. en todo caso `$pdf->Output('D',"nombre-del-archivo.pdf");` seria lo que buscas

Comment: Ya lo intente y me sigue saliendo lo mismo

Comment: He Editado el contenido de la pregunta

Comment: La cadena de error aparece en una nueva pestana?

intenta esto.

    `header("Content-Type: application/pdf");`
    `$pdf->Output('D','archivo.pdf',false);`
    `exit(0);`

Comment: @Ferny pudiste dar con la solución a dicho problema, estoy tratando de realizar lo mismo y no me genera la descarga. Aunque estoy usando AngularJS en vez de Ajax

Comment: @jecorrales no, no pude solucionarlo, alguien me explicaba que tenia que ver con la forma de interpretar de ajax, al ultimo recurri al `jsPDF`, pero realmente hasta ahorita no he dado con el error.

Comment: @FernyCortez, yo solucioné eso capturando las variables, mandandolas por medio de una URL concatenada y recibiendolas con PHP. Pero me tome con que esta libreria era muy basica para lo que pretendia realizar, por lo que tuve que usar HTML2PDF, la cual me permite tener una mayor facilidad de diseño de mis formatos PDF.

Comment: @jecorrales podrias dejar la solución?

Answer (score 0):

pienso que tu código tiene alguna salida "gráfica" o como le llamamos por pantalla, ya sea por warning, error o algún mensaje. Esto hace que FPDF devuelva esos caracteres por pantalla y no permite generar el archivo PDF. Podrías probar la ruta completa de la generación del PDF en tu navegador por ejemplo: http://localhost/xxxx/users/admin/gen_pdf_adm/genpdfrep.php y ver si genera el PDF sin problemas o muestra algún warning/mensaje.

Comment: El problema que tengo es que necesito pasar datos al PDF por eso uso el ajax, si ejecuto la linea que mencionaste si me genera el PDF, pero como mencione el problema es que necesito enviar datos y según leí tiene que ver algo con lo binario y me muestra el mensaje anterior,

Answer (score 0):

para CI4
Coloca esto en tu funcion

```
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

en el archivo .php del pdf despues de `$pdf->output()` inserta `exit;` y listo.

Me sucedió lo mismo, busqué mucho y eso fue la solución.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/402385)