# Problemas abriendo un archivo desde PHP en una nueva ventana

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo en una ruta del servidor y me gustaría poder enviarlo al navegador.

He intentado algo así:

```
<?php
$filepath = '/var/tmp/apiRest/download/'.$rst;

if(file_exists($filepath)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filepath).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
        flush(); // Flush system output buffer
        readfile($filepath);
        exit();
    }
```

Si la variable `$filepath` contiene el nombre del archivo en forma de variable `$rst`, no descarga el archivo, pero si le pongo la ruta completa a mano sí.

```
$filepath = '/var/tmp/apiRest/download/prueba.txt';
```

Haciendo un `echo` de la variable `$rst`, me da bien el nombre del archivo pero algo falla al concatenar.

La llamada al PHP desde el navegador, usando javascript, la realizo de la siguiente manera:

```
function loadDoc(id){ //funcion que me carga un documento y lo guarda en download
    var parametros = {
        "id": id,
    }

    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: "php/PlnDir/load_doc.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            window.open("php/PlnDir/load_doc.php");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: include '/var/tmp/apiRest/download/5730Turbo.txt'; No me ha funcionado, no me da ningun errror pero no abre el archivo, gracias

Comment: ¿Ese archivo contiene código? ¿Qué querés hacer con el archivo? Por favor danos un poco más de contexto para poder ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: Con el texto del archivo que vas ha hacer? descargarlo o vas a trabajarlo?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que `$rst` contiene `prueba.txt`? ¿Podrías mostrarme el resultado de ejecutar un `echo bin2hex($rst);`? Tiene toda la pinta de que tiene un espacio en blanco adicional o cualquier otro carácter adicional. Con lo que me pongas que muestra ese `echo` podré decirte qué está pasando.

Comment: este es el resultado del alert en el success de la funcion ajax  cuando devuelve el echo:  35373438547572626f2e747874 corresponde a un archivo llamado 5748Turbo.txt

Comment: Bien, el contenido es correcto. ¿Y dices que si pones `$filepath = '/var/tmp/apiRest/download/5748Turbo.txt';` te funciona correctamente la descarga?

Comment: Si, si lo pongo a mano lo hace bien, es bastante raro, desde ajax, hago un window.open("php/PlnDir/load_doc.php");  el archivo load_doc.php es el que contiene el código.

Comment: Por favor, confírmamelo: ¿Cuando pones a mano `/var/tmp/apiRest/download/5748Turbo.txt` o cuando pones a mano `/var/tmp/apiRest/download/prueba.txt`? Son dos archivos diferentes, puede ser que uno exista y que el otro no.

Comment: Si, me aseguro que el archivo existe, es mas si lo pongo a meno, cuando llamo al archivo  load_doc.php con window.open, este hace su funcion y me descarga el archivo  5748Turbo.txt

Comment: Lo único que necesito es poder descargar un archivo de una carpeta del servidor.

Comment: Has probado a comentar los header y enviar el archivo? No vaya a ser que esté dándote problemas esa parte del código?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un caso `else` en el `if(file_exists($filepath))` para que te haga un `echo "no se encontró el archivo";` en caso de fallar la condición? PD: Voy a solicitar que pasen a un chat esta conversación.

Comment: Si no existe el archivo, avisa que no existe, funciona bien la condición. En cualquier caso, cuando hago un alert al data de la funcion ajax, en el alert leo el archivo. Por si te vale de algo, la pagina intenta descargarlo, hace como si cargara y da este error: ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH. Debe de ser algo del nombre que me traigo de la BD, ya que si yo uso $rst="Turbo.txt" y  le paso $rst a la ruta, si lo hace. EL fallo es cuando lo traido de la bd

Comment: Pero entonces las pruebas que has estado haciendo con el `echo bin2hex($rst);` ¿las hiciste con los datos traídos de la base de datos o con asignación manual del contenido?

Comment: Con los datos que traida de la BD, la asignación manual funciona bien. lo que falla es cuando me traigo el nombre del archivo de la bd, lo asigno a la variable y esta la concateno con la ruta.

Comment: Vuelvo a insistir por si no me he explicado bien, ¿podrías mostrarme el `echo bin2hex($rst);` cuando se obtiene su valor de la base de datos?

Comment: SI, es el mismo que te he mostrado antes, pero vuelvo a hacerlo.  35373438547572626f2e747874

Comment: 2f7661722f746d702f617069526573742f646f776e6c6f61642f35373438547572626f2e747874 Esta es la variable $filepath. Aqui esta la ruta que pongo a pelo y la variable nombre de archivo ($rst). EL alert me sale extraño, Aunque veo bien toda la cadena, cuando lo quiero seleccionar me borra parte de ella.

Comment: @LorenzoMartín , [continuemos esta conversación en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82169/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-lorenzo-martin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás solicitando mediante una petición [`XHR` (`XMLHttpRequest`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) el archivo usando el método `POST` y enviando el identificador del archivo mediante la variable `id`:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        'id': id,
    },
    url: "php/PlnDir/load_doc.php",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        window.open("php/PlnDir/load_doc.php");
    }
});
```

Hasta ahí todo está correcto, pero no se puede disparar la descarga de un archivo mediante una petición `XHR` si no se agrega código adicional (en una siguiente edición expondré cómo hacerlo).

Para solventar ese problema has intentado abrir el PHP en una ventana nueva:

```
window.open("php/PlnDir/load_doc.php");
```

El problema es que la ventana abierta cargará el archivo PHP mediante el método `GET` normal, sin enviar ningún dato en la variable `id` (y tampoco lo hace por `POST` como se esperaba), por lo que esta nueva petición fallará y no encontrará ningún archivo que descargar si intentas hacer la búsqueda SQL con `$_POST['id']`.

Para detectar un envío fallido del parámetro `id` podría haber hecho la siguiente comprobación en el archivo PHP lo siguiente:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id']) === false) {
  die('Datos de "id" no recibidos');
}
```

Hay dos soluciones al problema. La más sencilla es enviar correctamente el parámetro por `POST` a la nueva ventana. Para ello podemos crear un formulario cuyo campo `id` no sea visible y que éste se cargue en `_blank` (ventana nueva):

```
<form action="php/PlnDir/load_doc.php" method="post"
    name="formulario" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" />
</form>
<script>
function loadDoc(id){ //funcion que me carga un documento y lo guarda en download
  document.formulario.id.value = id;
  document.formulario.submit();
}
</script>
```

La más compleja pasa por crear un `Blob` a partir de los datos recibidos por `XHR`, cargarlos en una etiqueta `<a>` y forzar su pulsación. En [esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/334329/18608) he creado un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score -1):

podrías incluir el archivo utilizando la función include

```
include '/var/tmp/apiRest/download/5730Turbo.txt';
```

- Añadir, que el archivo, debe estar en la misma carpeta (que el archivo al que añades el include) según te lo he puesto.

Comment: En este caso el archivo esta en otra carpeta, no me es posible modificarlo. en javascript uso window.open pero en php no conozco la función

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, nunca he probado hacerlo con ruta absoluta, pero debería funcionar, prueba y me dices

Comment: @JavierAvilaFernandez si el archivo es de texto, el `include` no le sirve. El `include` es para importar codigo a tu php. Cuando se encuentre que es texto, lo mas seguro es que saque errores. *tiene que producir un script PHP válido, porque será procesado en el servidor local* segun la advertencia de seguridad en [la documentacion de include en php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php)