# HEADER DOWNLOAD PHP IMPRIME SIMBOLOS EN LA CONSOLA

Tags: php, archivo

Alguien sabe porque al ejecutar el download con header() no descarga nada sino que imprime "cierto contenido" en la consola?

Mi codigo de descarga:

```
$idRecurso = isset($_POST["idRecurso"])?limpiarCadena($_POST["idRecurso"]):"";

        $rspta=$recursos->descargarRecurso($idRecurso);
        $reg = $rspta->fetch_object();
        $pdf = $reg->pdf_recurso;

        $ubicacion = '../files/recursos/'.$pdf;

        if (file_exists($ubicacion)) {
            header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); 
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$pdf);
            readfile('../files/recursos/' . $pdf);
        }
```

Una parte del resultado(ya que es muy largo):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería muchisimo cualquier ayuda o idea ya que llevo días sin resolver este problema, no se que estoy ignorando que no me permite completar la descarga. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que tiene que ver con un encoder/decoder (no sé si 64) que te hace falta...

Comment: Prueba con un archivo de tamaño pequeño y revisa que el nombre del archivo no contenga espacios.

Comment: Estimado, tengo un problema similar, lo has podido resolver?

Comment: El problema no está en el guión PHP, si no en el código JavaScript de tu página que está volcando a la consola el contenido de la respuesta de la llamada al PHP (a través de XHR o fetch). Si compartes el código JavaScript que provoca la descarga del PDF te podemos decir cómo hacer la descarga del contenido. 1ª referencia: [Error generar PDF con FPDF](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/388659/18608). 2ª: [Problemas abriendo archivo desde PHP en ventana nueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/191453/18608). 3ª: [CsvView no exporta CSV con llamada ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/334329/18608).