# CsvView (cakephp3) no me exporta el CSV mediante una llamada $.ajax

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Esa es mi petición `$ajax` para llamar a mi función del controlador donde le paso las fechas para limitar los registros a mostrar:

```
$( "#btcsv" ).click(function() {
    if(comprobar()){
        $mes = mes;
        $ano = ano;
        var dias = new Date(ano,mes,0).getDate();
        $fechainicio = ano+"-"+mes+"-1";
        $fechafinal = ano+"-"+mes+"-"+dias;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' =>'PedidosVentas', 'action' => 'export/pedidos', '_ext' => 'csv')); ?>',
            headers : {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val()
            },
            data:{
            fechainicio:$fechainicio,
            fechafinal:$fechafinal
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) 
            {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            },
            success(msg){
            },
            error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorMessage){
            console.log(errorMessage);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(xhr);
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        Swal.fire(
        'Ups!',
        'Parece que no has introducido una fecha',
        'error'
        )
    }
});
```

Y tengo en mi controlador en la función `initialize`:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
        'viewClassMap' => ['csv' => 'CsvView.Csv'
    ]]);
}
```

Y luego tengo mi función, a la que le paso la fecha para generar mi CSV:

```
public function export(){

    $this->loadModel('PedidosVentas');

    $inicio = $this->request->getData()['fechainicio'];
    $final = $this->request->getData()['fechafinal'];

    $pedidos = $this->PedidosVentas->find("all",array('conditions'=>array('fecha BETWEEN '.$inicio.' and '.$final.'')))->select(['cliente_id','usuario','centro_id','tipo_articulo_id'])->distinct('centro_id');
    $this->loadModel('Centros');
    $centro = $this->Centros->find()->all();
    $mes = date("m",strtotime($inicio));
    $ano = date("Y",strtotime($inicio));


   //$PedidosVentas2 = $this->PedidosVentas->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Centros.id','Centros.nombre'),'contain'=>array('Centros','TipoArticulos','Clientes','TipoComidas')),array('groupby'=>array('Centros')))->toArray();



    $this->loadModel('TipoArticulos');


    $dias = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN , $mes , $ano);
    $this->loadModel('Articulos');
    $this->loadModel('TipoComidas');

  $arrayTotal = [];
  $precio = 0;
  $total = 0;
  $total2 = 0;
    foreach ($centro as $c) 
    {
        $articulos = $this->Articulos->find('all')->select(['id','tipo_centro_id','tipo_comida_id','tipo_articulo_id','precio'])->where(['tipo_centro_id' =>$c->tipo_centro_id]);
        foreach ($articulos as $articulo)
        {
            $array['ID'] = $c->cliente_id;
            $array['Gerencia'] = $c->poblacion;
            $array['Centro'] = $c->nombre;
            //$array['ID_gerencia'] = $c->codigio_gerencia;
            $nombre1 = $this->TipoArticulos->find()->select(['nombre'])->where(['id'=>$articulo->tipo_articulo_id])->first();
            $nombre2 = $this->TipoComidas->find()->select(['tipo'])->where(['id'=>$articulo->tipo_comida_id])->first();
            $array['articulo'] = $nombre2->tipo." ".$nombre1->nombre;
            for($i=1; $i<=$dias ; $i++)
            {
                $array[$i] = $this->PedidosVentas->find()->where(['fecha' => $ano.'-'.$mes.'-'.$i , 'centro_id' => $c->id,'tipo_comida_id'=>$articulo->tipo_comida_id, 'tipo_articulo_id'=>$articulo->tipo_articulo_id])->count();
                if(isset($arrayT[$i]) == false){
                    $arrayT[$i] = 0;
                }
                $total2 = $total2 + $array[$i];
                $total = $total + $array[$i];
                $arrayT[$i] = $arrayT[$i] + $array[$i];
                $precio = $precio + ($articulo->precio*$array[$i]);
            }
            $array['totalp'] = $total2;
            $array['Precio'] = $articulo->precio."€";
            array_push($arrayTotal,$array);
            $total2 = 0;
        }


        $array['ID'] = "";
        $array['Gerencia'] = "";
        $array['Centro'] = "";
        //$array['ID_gerencia'] = "";
        $array['articulo'] = "Total Articulos";
        for($i=1; $i<=$dias ; $i++)
            {
                if(isset($arrayT[$i]) == false){
                    $arrayT[$i] = 0;
                }
                $array[$i] =  $arrayT[$i];
            }
        $array['totalp'] = $total;
        $array['Precio'] = $precio."€";
        array_push($arrayTotal,$array);
        $precio = 0;
        $total = 0;
        $arrayT=[];
    }

    $_serialize = 'arrayTotal';
    $_delimiter = ',';
    $_header = ['ID', 'Gerencia', 'Centro','articulo'];


    $dias = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN , $mes , $ano);
    for ($i=1; $i<=$dias ; $i++){
        array_push($_header,$i);
    }
    array_push($_header,'Total');
    array_push($_header,'Precio');

    $this->response = $this->response->withDownload('Pedidos.csv');
    $this->viewBuilder()->setClassName('CsvView.Csv');
    $this->set(compact('arrayTotal', '_serialize','_delimiter','_header'));
}
```

Y esto no me descarga el CSV generado, y no hay ningún error porque en *Network* veo que ha entrado bien a esa función y genera todo el contenido, pero no me descarga el CSV y no sé cuál puede ser el motivo.

Comment: ¿Te has dado cuenta que el evento `success` no tiene código? Es decir, recibes la información del PHP, pero no haces nada con esa información. ¿Qué tenías pensado hacer? ¿Provocar una descarga? En ese caso, ¿por qué necesitas hacerlo a través de `$.ajax` y no un formulario normal y corriente? Echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/191453/18608).

Comment: Mi idea es que cuando hago click en el boton me genere un csv, hice las pruebas sin la petición poniendo yo la fecha, y entonces si me lo generaba pero  al hacer la petición ajax ya no, puede que sea ese el fallo.

Comment: En la respuesta que te enlazo hago una explicación del problema que estás sufriendo. Convertir una petición XHR a una descarga no es 100% compatible con todos los navegadores, la solución 100% compatible es hacerlo mediante un formulario, pero si quieres te indico cómo hacerlo mediante javascript.

Comment: Vale, también me sirve, indícame como podría hacerlo y pruebo.

Comment: Ya tienes el ejemplo creado. Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás solicitando mediante una petición [`XHR` (`XMLHttpRequest`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) el archivo usando el método `POST`, enviando como parámetros el rango de fechas `fechainicio` y `fechafinal` en esa petición.

Debes entender que al completarse la petición XHR no haces nada con los datos (`success(msg) {}`), por lo que ni se descargan ni se almacenan en ningún lado, como es de esperar.

Tienes dos opciones:

- Hacer el trabajo con un formulario dinámico ([ver ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/191453/18608)).
- Cargar los datos en un `Blob` y forzar su descarga.

### Solución basada en `Blob`

Puedes crear la siguiente función en tu código para provocar la descarga de un archivo basado en los datos proporcionados en sus parámetros:

```js
function guardar(datos, archivo) {
  /* Vamos a crear un enlace virtual al que forzaremos el clic */
  let a = document.createElement('a');
  /* Lo agregamos al DOM oculto */
  a.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  /* Ahora creamos un objeto Blob con los datos proporcionados */
  let blob = new Blob([ datos ], { type: 'octet/stream' });
  let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  /* Asignamos esos datos al enlace creado y forzamos el clic */
  a.href = url;
  a.download = archivo;
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
/* Esta es una ejecución para pruebar su correcto funcionamiento */
guardar('5;2;6', 'pruebas.csv');
```

Tendrás que modificar tu evento `success` de la siguiente manera para hacer uso de la función creada:

```
 success(msg) {
   guardar(msg, 'Pedidos.csv');
 },
```