# ¿porque no funciona reporte?

Tags: php

hola quisiera que alguien me ayudara, subi mi pagina al hosuting y quedi listo, funciona los modulos de resgistrar consultar pero cuando le doy reportes me aparece un error que es este:

Error fatal : no detectado Excepción: error de FPDF: algunos datos ya se han enviado, no se pueden enviar archivos PDF (la salida se inició en /storage/ssd5/736/17416736/public_html/bd/conexion.php:1) en / storage / ssd5 /736/17416736/public_html/reporte_clientes/fpdf.php:271 Seguimiento de pila: # 0 /storage/ssd5/736/17416736/public_html/reporte_clientes/fpdf.php(1049): FPDF-> Error ('Algunos datos tienen un. .. ') # 1 /storage/ssd5/736/17416736/public_html/reporte_clientes/fpdf.php(999): FPDF -> _ checkoutput () # 2 /storage/ssd5/736/17416736/public_html/reporte_clientes/index.php (70): FPDF-> Output () # 3 {main} incluido en /storage/ssd5/736/17416736/public_html/reporte_clientes/fpdf.php en la línea 271

noo se aque se deba esto ya revise en esa carpeta que manda pero no encuentro como solcuinarlo alguien porfavor

Comment: Googlea: "error de FPDF: algunos datos ya se han enviado, no se pueden enviar archivos PDF" si incluyes con comillas mejor. encontrarás todos los blogs que han tirado exactamente el mismo problema.

Comment: Por ejemplo acá: [click](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140457/error-al-generar-pdf-con-la-libreria-fpdf) hay muchos comentarios de lo que podría ser dada la información que brindas.